# OpenMP and internal subroutines

Tags: fortran, openmp

I've been testing OpenMP speedup of simple Fortran code with 1) internal subroutine call inside parallel region and 2) parallel region initialization inside internal subroutine. In both cases openmp do loop were placed inside internal subroutine. Here this simple code:

```
module module_with_subroutine

include "omp_lib.h"

integer ,parameter  :: rkind = selected_real_kind(15,307)
real(rkind)     ,dimension(100,100,100)  :: A    
real(rkind) :: elapsed_time
integer     :: clock_start ,clock_end ,clock_rate

contains

subroutine module_subprogram

A = 3.14_rkind

call SYSTEM_CLOCK(count_rate = clock_rate)
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(count = clock_start)

!!$omp parallel num_threads(12)                         !!! For case 1

call intrinsic_subprogram

!!$omp end parallel

call SYSTEM_CLOCK(count = clock_end)

elapsed_time = (clock_end-clock_start)/real(clock_rate,rkind)

print *, 'Elapsed time in seconds: ',elapsed_time
print *, 'Clock start: ',clock_start
print *, 'Clock end: ',clock_end
print *, 'Clock rate: ',clock_rate

contains

    subroutine intrinsic_subprogram
        integer :: i, j, k, steps ,nthread

        do steps = 1,10000
            !$omp parallel num_threads(12)               !!! For case 2
            !$omp do collapse(3) private (i,j,k,nthread)
            do k = 1,100
            do j = 1,100
            do i = 1,100
                nthread = omp_get_thread_num()
                A(i,j,k) = (exp(A(i,j,k)**3.14 + sqrt(A(i,j,k)**3.14) + log(A(i,j,k)**3.14)))**1.414
                if(A(i,j,k) <= 3.14) then
                   A(i,j,k) = 1.0
                end if 
                !print *, 'thread number',nthread
                !print *, 'i,j,k',i,j,k
            end do
            end do
            end do
            !$omp end do
            !$omp end parallel
        end do

    end subroutine

end subroutine

end module
```

Strange thing here is that second case is always a bit faster than first one, despite multiple parallel regions initializations inside steps loop. Maybe somebody can explain this behaviour ? I'm new to OpenMP programming and maybe I'm misunderstanding OpenMP thread forking technology. Thank you in advance !

Comment: How big is the time difference? How did you time things? Did you do statistics?

Comment: OT, but I really recommend `!$use omp_lib` instead of the include.

Comment: Yes, I've tried several times. Difference is really small, about 75s vs 80s. Timing section is inside code,and beside that I did VTune analysis, and it shows similar feature.

Comment: Vladimir F, thanks  for your remark!

Comment: Your first case is very strange for me : do you know that you create 12 instances of your subroutine intrinsic_subprogram ???

Comment: Well, I thought about that, but it seems to work properly. I've checked thread numbers in intrinsic subroutine loop and it looks just same as in case 2. Besides, if it worked as you suggest elapsed time would be much larger and equal to sequential case at best..

Comment: I don't agree. What is the cost of the sequential case ? I tested your program in printing the variable "steps" (in limiting the loop bound to 100). I got 12 times the number 1, twelve times the number 2 ... So the first test is not correct because each element of the matrix A may be modifiede simultaneously by several threads...

Comment: Thank you Francois ! You absolutely right, first test does not provide correct answer. But I cannot understand why i have a speedup in that case. Logically , each thread should execute intrinsic_subroutine independently and elapsed time for each thread should be equal to sequential case..